# Using Pillow in Django with pathlib instead of os

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, pathlib

I'm doing a project in Django 4.0.6, which uses pathlib instead of os. I installed Pillow to include an image in the user's profile, but when I try to save the image I get the following error:

> TypeError at /admin/account/profile/2/change/  expected str, bytes or
> os.PathLike object, not tuple

Relevant code:

settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR, 'media'
```

app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Profile
from .forms import LoginForm, UserRegistrationForm, UserEditForm, ProfileEditForm


@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'account/home.html', {'section': 'home'})


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()
            Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})


@login_required
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(
                                    instance=request.user.profile,
                                    data=request.POST,
                                    files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile updated successfully')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error updating your profile')
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request,
                  'account/edit.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form,
                   'profile_form': profile_form})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('edit/', views.edit, name='edit'),
]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Profile for user {self.user.username}'
```

If I import os and set MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/'), then it works, but I would prefer using pathlib, and no mixing pathlib and os, this is just a personal preference, but I would like to understand why this error is happening.

Below is the tracebak complete:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL:
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/account/profile/2/change/
>
> Django Version: 4.0.6 Python Version: 3.10.4 Installed Applications:
> ['account.apps.AccountConfig',  'django.contrib.admin',
> 'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
> 'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages',
> 'django.contrib.staticfiles'] Installed Middleware:
> ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 55, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 197, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 683, in wrapper
> return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
> line 133, in _wrapped_view
> response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py",
> line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
> response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
> return view(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1888, in change_view
> return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)   File
> "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
> line 46, in _wrapper
> return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
> line 133, in _wrapped_view
> response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1745, in changeform_view
> return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)   File
> "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1797, in _changeform_view
> self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1220, in save_model
> obj.save()   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 806, in save
> self.save_base(   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 857, in save_base
> updated = self._save_table(   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 961, in _save_table
> values = [   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 965, in 
> (getattr(self, f.attname) if raw else f.pre_save(self, False)),   File
> "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py",
> line 316, in pre_save
> file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py",
> line 92, in save
> self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)   File
> "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py",
> line 56, in save
> name = self.get_available_name(name, max_length=max_length)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py",
> line 96, in get_available_name
> while self.exists(name) or (max_length and len(name) > max_length):   File
> "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py",
> line 362, in exists
> return os.path.lexists(self.path(name))   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py",
> line 376, in path
> return safe_join(self.location, name)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
> line 49, in **get**
> res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/Users/ro/CS/rypptc/polmanv0.0.0.1/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py",
> line 256, in location
> return os.path.abspath(self.base_location)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/posixpath.py",
> line 378, in abspath
> path = os.fspath(path)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/account/profile/2/change/
> Exception Value: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Comment: Two pages of error messages but no runnable code that produced them?

Comment: This is because it seems the problem is not in the code. If I use a previous Django version to 3.1, then the code works fine, so I included just the related code in settings.py, but after Django 3.1 I get this error.

Comment: That information belongs in your question. Please click [edit] and add it in.